# Prove that every group of order 70 contains at least four proper normal subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Prove that every group of order 70 contains at least four proper normal subgroups.

According to my guesses, the task is solved by the third theorem of Sylow and decomposition into a union of conjugacy classes.

Comment: Try showing that there exists only one $k$-Sylow-Subgroup for a prime $k\: \big|\: |G|$. By Sylow 3 that subgroup must then be normal (i.e. it's conjugated to itself, the definition of a normal subgroup). Though, that'll only get you to at least 3 at most.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We can find these 3 by such reasoning: Suppose that G is a group of order 70=7 • 5 • 2 . The number of Sylow 5-subgroups: has the form 5n+1 and 5n + 1 and divides 14. This means that their number must be equal to 1, which means that there is a unique (normal) Sylow 5-subgroup P . The number of Silovsky 7-subgroups: has the form 7n+1 and 7n + 1 and divides 10. Hence, it must be equal to 1, hence there is a unique (normal) Sylow 7-subgroup Q . The product PQ=QP is also a normal subgroup of order 35. One more is missing, because the trivial subgroup, as far as I know, is not proper.

Comment: There are only $4$ groups of order $70$ ($Z/(70), D_{70}, Z/(5)\times D_7, Z/(7)\times D_5$

Comment: @PropockekKokosepchich That last comment should not be a comment, it should be part of your question.

Comment: A proper subgroup is a subgroup that is not equal to the group itself, so the trivial subgroup is a proper subgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Sylow's theorems we easily get that the Sylow $5,7$ subgroups are normal.

Then $HK$ is of index $2$, where $H,K$ are those two subgroups, since $\lvert HK\rvert =\lvert H\rvert \lvert K\rvert/ \lvert H\cap K\rvert=35 $, by the second isomorphism theorem.

The fourth is the trivial subgroup.